# Laravel Eureka client error 404 not found Response

Tags: laravel

I have error!!! Please help!!!
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException : Client error: POST  http://10.100.0.7:8080/eureka/apps/NewsService resulted in a 404 Not Found response

```
public function handle()
{
    $client = new EurekaClient([
        'eurekaDefaultUrl' => 'http://10.100.0.7:8080/eureka-
                server/eureka',
        'hostName'         => 'NewsService',
        'appName'          => 'NewsService',
        'ip'               => '10.111.2.23',
        'port'             => ['8000', true],
    ]);

    try {
        $client->register();
        $client->start();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have a error in your catch block `$echo`.

Comment: Where are the endpoints defined? Please can you also add a link to the package you're using.

Comment: https://github.com/piwvh/php-eureka

Answer (score 0):

Create laravel console  command and use  https://github.com/PavelLoparev/php-eureka-client